# How to make a button: 1. activate a bean's method and 2. navigate to a bookmarkable (!) location

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

h:button can navigate to a bookmarkable link, but can not call beans' methods

h:commandButton can make calls to beans' methods, and can use action attribute to navigate to somewhere but it wont be a bookmarkable location

The question is how to make a button do both

Example:

We got two JSF pages:
   list.xhtml
   item.xhtml

item.xhtml?id=5 opens the page with the item #5's data. There's also a "Save" button

How to make "Save" button 1. save data and 2. navigate back to list so there would be "list.xhtml" in the browser's address field and not "item.xhtml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just return something like this from the action method:

```
return "/list.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
```

This will send a redirect to the client and the client will then fetch the list page in a separate GET request.

Comment: That simple? Wow! Thank you chkal!